# Output foreach loop to html

Tags: powershell

So, here's my issue... I have the below PowerShell script that I want to use to do the following:

1. Pull Each Hyper-V cluster member (currently 29 x Server 2016 nodes)
2. Run a `ForEach` loop on each node to get all VMs that have Hyper-V replication enabled.
3. Combine all 29 outputs into a single .html file with table formatting.

Here is the code:

```
$Cluster = Get-ClusterNode -Cluster hv-cluster01.contoso.com


$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:peachpuff;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color:  black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{column-width: 200px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:thistle}"
$a = $a + "TD{column-width: 200px;border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:PaleGoldenrod;text-align: center}"
$a = $a + "</style>"

ForEach ($Node in $Cluster)
{
Get-VMReplication -ComputerName $Node | Select-Object VMName, State, Health, PrimaryServer | ConvertTo-HTML -head $a -body "<H2>DR Replication Status</H2>" | Out-File C:\Scripts\Test.htm
}
```

My ultimate goal would be to put this into a scheduled task to run 2-3 times per day, and using `Send-MailMessage`, send the html content in the body of an eamil, to myself and others on my team.

I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you convert and output the object for each $Node in $Cluster. Instead you first have to populate your final object, which contains all information, and then convert and output these information.

You do so, by moving the convert and output part outside the loop. For example:

```
$Cluster = Get-ClusterNode -Cluster hv-cluster01.contoso.com


$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:peachpuff;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color:  black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{column-width: 200px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:thistle}"
$a = $a + "TD{column-width: 200px;border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:PaleGoldenrod;text-align: center}"
$a = $a + "</style>"

$Report = ForEach ($Node in $Cluster) {
    Get-VMReplication -ComputerName $Node | Select-Object VMName, State, Health, PrimaryServer
}

$Report | ConvertTo-HTML -head $a -body "<H2>DR Replication Status</H2>" | Out-File C:\Scripts\Test.htm
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! That worked perfect for outputting to the html file. I've added one other part that i'll post below. Maybe you could tell me what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the script quite a bit more, to accommodate the rest of what I was trying to do...

I've managed to get the script to pull the content of the HTML file and place it into an email message. My problem is, some of the table style info isn't transferring to the email. Specifically, the `column-width` part. So all of the table entries are squished together. See below:

```
Remove-Item C:\Scripts\ReplicationHealth.htm

$Cluster = Get-ClusterNode -Cluster hv-cluster01.contoso.com

$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:LightGrey;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color:  black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{column-width: 200px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:DodgerBlue}"
$a = $a + "TD{column-width: 200px;border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:PapayaWhip;text-align: center}"
$a = $a + "</style>"

$Report = ForEach ($Node in $Cluster) {
Get-VMReplication -ComputerName $Node | Select-Object VMName, State, Health, PrimaryServer
}

$time = Get-Date -Format G

$Report | ConvertTo-HTML -head $a -body "<H2>Hyper-V Replication Status</H2>", $time | Out-File C:\Scripts\ReplicationHealth.htm

$MailBody = Get-Content C:\Scripts\ReplicationHealth.htm -Raw

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "SERVERIP" -From "HyperV-Replication@contoso.com" -To "User@contoso.com" -Subject "Hyper-V Replication Status" -Body $MailBody -BodyAsHtml
```

A tiny bit more help would be awesome! 
Thanks in advance!